# Factory Girl with serialized Array "TypeError: can't cast Array to text"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

This very related question's answer does not work for me: [Factory Girl with serialized field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281112/factory-girl-with-serialized-field)

I am trying to use Factory Girl to set a serialized Array field in a nested factory and getting:

```
TypeError:
    can't cast Array to text
```

Models:

```
class Transmission < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Letter < Transmission
  serialize :genders, Array
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transmission do
    factory :letter do
      genders ["male", "female"]
    end
  end
end
```

in spec

```
FactoryGirl.create(:letter)
```

the genders field is of type text in the postges db

factory_girl 4.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the FactoryGirl.create(:letter) was a Transmission instance which does not have:

```
serialize :genders, Array
```

I had to add the class name to the nested factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transmission do
    factory :letter, class: Letter do
      genders ['male', 'female']
    end
  end
end
```